# Using nomnoml within jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, uml, nomnoml

I'd like to draw UML diagrams within jupyter and I've been trying to achieve this using [nomnoml](https://www.nomnoml.com/) with one of the jupyter magics `%%javascript` or `%%html` but I can't seem to get it to render.

For instance using [this simple example from nomnoml](https://github.com/skanaar/nomnoml#html-canvas-rendering-target):

```html
%%html
<script src="//unpkg.com/graphre/dist/graphre.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/nomnoml/dist/nomnoml.js"></script>

<canvas id="target-canvas"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('target-canvas');
    var source = '[nomnoml] is -> [awesome]';
    nomnoml.draw(canvas, source);
</script>
```

...the output is blank and using browser inspection I noticed these errors:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: nomnoml is not defined`
`Uncaught ReferenceError: graphre is not defined`

Also tried a slight variation with `graphre.js` and `nomnoml.js` saved to my notebook directory.  This snippet in an html file renders properly in the browser but not from a jupyter cell.

```
%%html
<html>
<script src="graphre.js"></script>
<script src="nomnoml.js"></script>
<canvas id="target-canvas"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('target-canvas');
    var source = '[nomnoml] is -> [awesome]';
    nomnoml.draw(canvas, source);
</script>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**: the problem only appears to be with jupyter notebook, with jupyter lab both variants work as expected.

Comment: it seems the answer lies [here](https://www.stefaanlippens.net/jupyter-custom-d3-visualization.html) with using `require.config` although I can't get this to work with nomnoml.